# Calling a dictionary from another function

Tags: python, dictionary

guys I am having problems calling the dictionary into the next function. The first function returns the tuple

```
{'CSCA20': ['2017-12-13', '14:00'], 'CSCA67': ['2017-12-18', '9:00'], 'CSCA08': ['2017-12-13', '9:00']}
```

But when I try to call and print it in the second function I get an empty tuple. Anyone know why and how I could go about fix the error?

```
def create_course_dict(openfile):
    d = {}
    f = openfile
    f.readline()
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip().split(',')
        d[line[0]] = line[1:]

    return d

def ceate_date_dict(d):
    old_dict = {}
    old_dict = create_course_dict(openfile)
    print(old_dict)

with open('courses.csv') as openfile:
    print(create_course_dict(openfile))
    d = (create_course_dict(openfile)) 
    ceate_date_dict(d)
```

Comment: That's a dictionary, not a tuple.

Comment: You've already read the file with `readline` when you run `create_course_dict`, so there's nothing left to read when you run `ceate_date_dict`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're calling `create_course_dict()` twice. The first call reads all the lines in the file, and you print the dictionary.

When you call it the second time, you're at the end of the file, so there's nothing left for it to read. So the second call returns an empty dictionary.

There isn't really a reason to call it twice. Call it once, assign the result to a variable, then use the variable:

```
with open('courses.csv') as openfile:
    d = (create_course_dict(openfile)) 
    print(d)
    ceate_date_dict(d)
```

But if you really want to be able to call it multiple times, you can have it seek to the beginning of the file first.

```
def create_course_dict(openfile):
    d = {}
    f = openfile
    f.seek(0)
    f.readline()
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip().split(',')
        d[line[0]] = line[1:]

    return d
```